# Kafka Connect export multiple event types from same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use a new feature (https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/) regarding storing two 
different types of events on the same topic. Actually I am using Confluent version 4.1.0 and set these properties below 
to make this happen

```
properties.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY,TopicRecordNameStrategy.class.getName());
properties.put("value.multi.type", true);
```

Data are written to topic without issues and can be seen from a Kafka Streams application as Generic Avro Records. Also
on the Kafka Schema registry two new entries are created one for each event hosted on that specific topic.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot export these data from this topic using Kafka Connect. In the simplest case when
I use a File Sink Connector as below

```
{
  "name": "sink-connector",
  "config": {
      "topics": "source-topic",
      "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max": 1,
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://kafka-schema-registry:8081",
      "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://kafka-schema-registry:8081",
      "value.subject.name.strategy":"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy",
      "file": "/tmp/sink-file.txt"
    }
}
```

I get an error from the Connector that seems to be some kind of serialization error based on AvroConverter like
the one shown here

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: source-topic
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:468)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 2
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:202)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:229)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:296)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:284)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersionFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:125)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersion(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:236)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:152)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:194)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:120)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:468)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note that schema registry has an Avro schema with id 2 and another with schema id 3 that describe the two events hosted on the
same topic. Same issues arise when using JDBC connector.

So how do I handle this case in order to export data from my Kafka Cluster
to an external system. Am I missing something on my configuration ? Is it possible to have a topic with multiple type of events 
and export them through Kafka Connect ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. My code was passing key as String and value as avro. Hive-sink while reading tried to lookup for avro schema of key and was not able to find it. 
Adding the property
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
helped resolve the issue.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the schema of the Avro files created by connect? `union[typeA, typeB]`? Or perhaps: `record wrapper { { null, typeA} a, { null, typeB } b }`?